# Insert new document using Python Elastic Client raises illegal_argument_exception

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch service setup on AWS with an existing index that I'm trying to add more documents to.  I want to use the Python Elasticsearch Client to interact with this service.  I'm able to successfully connect the the service and query it as expected.  However, when I go to add new documents to Elasticsearch, I receive the following error:

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper [city] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]')
```

Do I need to somehow specify the mapping for each document that I add Elasticsearch?  I've searched through the documentation but haven't seen any examples of this. I would like to keep the city field mapped as a keyword, but I don't know how to specify that when uploading the new document.

***Here is my current process:***

```
# create auth for AWS version 4
awsauth = AWS4Auth(access_key, secret_key, "us-east-2", "es")

# instantiate the elastic search client
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

# create a document to upload
data = {'ad_id': 1053674,
 'city': 'Houston',
 'category': 'Cars',
 'date_posted': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 19, 33),
 'title': '2020 Chevrolet Silverado',
 'body': "This brand new vehicle is the perfect truck for you.",
 'phone': None}

# add document to index
res = es.index(index='ads', doc_type="doc", id=data[0]['ad_id'], body=data[0])
print(res['result'])
```

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper [city] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]')
```

Note: here is the output fomo `es.info()`:

```
{'name': '123456789', 'cluster_name': '123456789:ads', 'cluster_uuid': '123456789', 'version': {'number': '7.9.1', 'build_flavor': 'oss', 'build_type': 'tar', 'build_hash': 'unknown', 'build_date': '2020-11-03T09:54:32.349659Z', 'build_snapshot': False, 'lucene_version': '8.6.2', 'minimum_wire_compatibility_version': '6.8.0', 'minimum_index_compatibility_version': '6.0.0-beta1'}, 'tagline': 'You Know, for Search'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is thrown when you've tinkered with ingesting docs in a some way, Elasticsearch auto-generated a mapping for your index, and you were then trying to ingest documents that do not necessarily conform to the previously defined structure (mapping).

To [check the current mapping](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.10.1/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.get_mapping), run:

```py
current_mapping = es.indices.get_mapping('ads')
```

Now, to actually fix the original problem, drop the index and explicitly specify a mapping so you can be in full control of your ES index's structure:

```py
# create a document to upload
data = [{
    'ad_id': 1053674,
    'city': 'Houston',
    'category': 'Cars',
    'date_posted': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 29, 19, 33),
    'title': '2020 Chevrolet Silverado',
    'body': "This brand new vehicle is the perfect truck for you.",
    'phone': None
}]

mapping = '''
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "ad_id" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "body" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "category" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "city" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "date_posted" : {
        "type" : "date"
      },
      "title" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'''

# drop the index
# es.indices.delete(index='ads', ignore=[400, 404])

# create the index w/ the mapping
es.indices.create(index='ads', ignore=400, body=mapping)

# add document to index
res = es.index(index='ads', doc_type="_doc", id=data[0]['ad_id'], body=data[0])

print(res['result'])
```

FYI — if you intend to keep the `city` mapped as a [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), only exact matches will be possible when querying.